# Настройка SIP-телефона (KX-HDV100)

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

Есть KX-HDV100 и asterisk 11.2 на CentOS 6.5, астериск работает с софтофонами и SIP-телефоном Panasonic KX-TGP500, суть в том, что настройки у телефонов почти идентичны, но с HDV100 возникают проблемы при авторизации, CLI постоянно выдает

**NOTICE[4717]: chan_sip.c:28353 handle_request_register: Registration from

'< sip:13@192.168.1.100 >' failed for '192.168.1.112:5060' - Wrong password**

1.100 - сервер, 1.112 - телефонный аппарат.

sip.conf:

[13]
username = 13
secret = sova
context = dongle-incoming
type - friend
host = dynamic
callerid = 13

TGP500 настроеный так-же работает, только там юзернейм не цифровой, а буквенный, HDV100 же требует совпадения номера и идентификатора пользователя, вся разница, но пароль постоянно не верный.

Телефон настроил по мануалу (стр. 108)

[KX-HDV100 Administrator guide](http://cs.psn-web.net/support/sipphone_net/download/HDV1/manual/hdv100/ag/HDV100_AG%28ru%29_ZA.pdf)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В sip.conf.sample написано: `Note: The parameter "username" is not the username and in most cases is not needed at all. Check below. In later releases, it's renamed to "defaultuser" which is a better name, since it is used in combination with the "defaultip" setting.` 
Поправьте, для начала.

Comment: Да, и `type - friend`, там "=" должно быть.

Comment: вместо user сделать defaultuser или я не верно понял?

Comment: Да, `defaultuser = 13` вместо `username = 13`

Comment: Заинтересовало "In later releases", это начиная с какой версии следующие релизы начинаются?

Comment: Это сообщение еще начиная с 1.8 ветки есть. Да и в примерах фигурирует defaultuser везде.

Comment: Спасибо) в который раз спасаете)